# how to calculate the time needed to get from one point to another using google map api?

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to make a function that will calculate time needed for reaching from one point to another.

I have the following parameters:

```
   $latA = 40.640;
   $longA = 22.944;
   $latB = 40.641;
   $longB = 22.959;

  function durationFromCoordinatesStreetWay($latA, $longA, $latB, $longB) {


  $sendRequest = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/output?parameters"; 


  }
```

Anyone can help me to do this?

I have to use directions method. I will output the result as xml later on.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working page:

http://jsfiddle.net/GKSqB/

**ADDED: Version with latLngs** (needs real places to work)

http://jsfiddle.net/aL7yL/

It's close to the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions